# Error to start a chaincode on hyperledger fabric

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, chaincode

I am following the steps to use the Fabric test network from the hyperledger fabric, when I try to start the chaincode always have the following message:

```
Error: failed to read chaincode package at 'basic.tar.gz': open basic.tar.gz: no such file or directory
+ PACKAGE_ID=
Error: failed to normalize chaincode path: 'go list' failed with: go: inconsistent vendoring in /home/blamazales/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go:
        github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go@v0.0.0-20220720122508-9207360bbddd: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        github.com/hyperledger/fabric-contract-api-go@v1.2.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go@v0.0.0-20220613214546-bf864f01d75e: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        github.com/stretchr/testify@v1.8.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
        google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.0: is explicitly required in go.mod, but not marked as explicit in vendor/modules.txt
```

I updated the go to the version 1.18 and I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Also I tried to add these items on the modules.txt as mentioned to be not marked but still not working, unless I'm including it wrong or not be possible do this manually. Any ideas? And I'm trying to start the chaincode and run all the sample from hyperledger tutorial

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow: You should provide - or at least sketch - a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I miss some infos to change at module.txt when include these infos required as change the version of go that was in the file 1.17 to 1.18 which I am using